# Get coordinates in device system for a vector "static" in world system (android)

Tags: android, matrix, coordinates

I have seen similar questions on SO but none was answered... I guess it's a really stupid question, or maybe an stupid error that leads to a meaningless question. I guess it's more a Math related question that a programming question. Anyway I've been struggling for two weeks so I hope you can help me !

I would like to use M=SensorManager.getRotationMatrix() to find the coordinates of a "static" vector (coordinates are constants in world system) in the device system. When I use the matrix in opengl everything goes well but when I try to write some code myself I get some values I can't understand.

For example, i have a vector pointing north from the center of the device screen. Let's call it y. 
The coordinates of y in the world system are y(0,1,0) and they don't change. But these coordinates values change in the device system if I rotate the device, and become y'(y1,y2,y3). I would like to know y1,y2 and y3.

I tried  y' = M*y, but I can't figure out what are the values I get : they don't match with anything I would expect when I rotate the device. I thought it would rotate the device's y vector (pointing the camera) so it aligns to earth magnetic north, and that the coordinates I got would be in the device's system. That's actually what happens when I use the matrix in opengl.multmatrix... The vector is rotated and always pointing north.

I also tried to remap the rotation matrix, because I use a transformer pad and it seems that it is actually the x vector that points towards the camera. But y' values were not what I expected either and I didn t need to do that with opengl.
So what I am missing in the theory if I want to do opengl's job by hand, and what is actually M*y ?  Should I use M transpose, because what I actually want is to change the system I expressed my vector in ? (I also tried that but again, I failed).
Any detailed answer is welcome... Thank you.